# I want to Add multiple images and other data at a time using WCF in asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm new to `WCF`, I want to `Upload Multiple Images at a time` using `WCF` from client,

The scenario is : I have 20 questions and each question may have 0 to 2 images , So I have to request to the service to save all data, What are the possible ways to get it right?,

I'm trying to get from last two days, But I'm able insert one Image at a time....

Comment: Convert the images to stream and then store it to server

Comment: Is it possible make all images into stream or is there any way to use stream array

Comment: Of course you can, Just convert image to stream and pass it to parameter of webservice.

Comment: Hw it is possible to make all images into one stream,please Can you show me the code and thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the stream conversion for each image and add the details to a list.

in the client side.

```
  Stream stream = (Stream)openDialog.File.OpenRead();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                    stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                    BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                    {
                        bmi.SetSource(ms);
                        newRow.Thumbnail = bmi;
                }
```

in your service side

```
 string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ImageUploadPath");

                          if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
                          {
                              Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
                          }

                          filePath = filePath + "\\" + picture.FileName + "." + picture.FileType;

                          if (picture.FileName != string.Empty)
                          {
                              fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                              writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
                              writer.Write(picture.FileStream);
                          }
```

Comment: How this help in Multiple Image Uploading ? As OP mention he's able to insert one Image at a time

Comment: Add the image details to a list and in the service side we need to read one by one and upload

Comment: It wod me more helpfull for OP , If u edit ur answer accordingly

Comment: With this we can perform only one image at a time...I want to upload multiple images at a time

Comment: @PraveenKumarCh You can upload at once with this. am doing currenly now

Comment: If possible mail me the code with config file. my mail id : chpraveen31@gmail.com     thankz thankz